# EC2 - MongoDB - PyMongo - Debugging Query Latency

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, pymongo

I have 2 EC2 instances, one as a mongodb server and the other is a python web app (same availability zone). The python sever connects to mongo server using PyMongo and everything works fine.

The problem is, when I profile execution-time in python, in some calls (less than 5%) it takes even up to couple of second to return. I was able to narrow down the problem and the time delay was actually on the db calls to mongo server.

The two causes that I thought were, 
1. The Mongo server is slow/over-loaded 
2. Network latency

So, I tried upgrading the mongo servers to 4X faster instance but the issue still happens (Some calls takes even 3 secs to return) I assumed since both the servers are on EC2, network latency should not be a problem... but may be I was wrong.

How can I confirm if the issue is actually the network itself? If so, what the best way to solve it? Is there any other possible cause?

Any help is appreciated...

Thanks,

UPATE: The entities that I am fetching are very small (indexed) and usually the calls takes only 0.01-0.02 secs to finish.

UPDATE:

As suggested by "James Wahlin", I enabled profiling on my mongo server and got some interesting logs,

> Fri Mar 15 18:05:22 [conn88635] query db.UserInfoShared query: { $or:
>   [ { _locked: { $exists: false } }, { _locked: { $lte:
>   1363370603.297361 } } ], _id: "750837091142" } nto return:1 nscanned:1 nreturned:1 reslen:47 2614ms
>
> Fri Mar 15 18:05:22 [conn88635] command db.$cmd command: {
>   findAndModify: "UserInfoShared", fields: { _id: 1 }, upsert: true,
>   query: { $or: [ { _locked: { $exists: false } },  { _locked: { $lte:
>   1363370603.297361 } } ], _id: "750837091142" }, update: { $set: { _locked: 1363370623.297361 } }, new: true } ntoreturn:1 reslen:153 2614ms

You can see these two calls took more than 2 secs to finish. The field `_id` is unique indexed and finding it should not have taken this much time. May be I have to post a new question for it, but can the mongodb GLOBAL LOCK be the cause ?

Comment: Have you enabled slow query profiling in your mongod process? This would tell you whether the time is being spent within MongoDB. See the following for more info: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Comment: The issue is that the delay happens randomly and I need to associate a python process with mongo query time. Yes, the profiler logs the slow queries but associating that with particular python request is difficult. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an id to the queries that you can use to line up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@James Wahlin, thanks a lot for helping me out.

As it turned out the main cause of latency was mongodb `GLOBAL LOCK` itself. We had a lock percentage which was averaging at 5% and sometime peaks up to 30-50% and that results in the slow queries.

If you are facing this issue, the first thing you have to do it enable mongodb MMS service (`mms.10gen.com`), which will give you a lot of insights on what exactly is happening in your db server.

In our case the LOCK PERCENTAGE was really high and there were multiple reasons for it. First thing you have to do to figure it out is to read mongodb documentation on concurrency,
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/

The reason for lock can be in application level, mongodb or hardware.

1) Our app was doing a lot of `updates` and each update(more than `100 ops/sec`) holds a `global lock` in mongodb. The issue was that when an update happens for an entry which is not in memory, mongo will have to load the data into memory first and then update (in memory) and the whole process happens while inside the `global lock`. If say the whole thing takes 1 sec to complete (`0.75sec` to load the data from disk and `0.25sec` to update in memory), the whole rest of the update calls waits (for the entire `1 sec`) and such updates starts queuing up... and you will notice more and more slows requests in your app server.

The solution for it (while it might sound silly) is to `query` for the same data before you make an `update`. What it effectively does is moving the 'load data to memory' (0.75sec) part out of the `global lock` which greatly reduces your `lock percentage`

2) The other main cause of global lock is mongodb's data `flush` to disk. Basically in every 60sec (or less) mongodb (or the OS) writes the data to disk and a `global lock` is held during this process. (This kinda explains the random slow queries). In your MMS stats, see the graph for `background flush avg`... if its high, that means you have to get faster disks.

In our case, we moved to a new `EBS optimized` instance in `EC2` and also bumped our provisioned `IOPS` from `100` to `500` which almost halved the `background flush avg` and the servers are much happier now.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the great explanation. Could you please tell us how many reads/ups/writes you have per second (avg or total)? I'm just interested to see the size of your traffic. Many thanks.